# How to add new parameters (key/value pair) to QuerySnapshot document in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Before I upgraded flutter and firestore to `cloud_firestore: ^0.14.4` I was able to add new `isSelected` paramenter to the collection from firestore with this piece of code. I used this parameter to help me with my selection operations in the list without having to have the field in the database.

```
var data = Firestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .document(firebaseid)
          .collection('contacts')
          .getDocuments();
      data.then((QuerySnapshot contacts) {
        if (contacts.documents.isNotEmpty) {
          for (var contact in contacts.documents) {
            contact.data['isSelected'] = false;       <-- Adding isSelected param
            _myContacts.add(contact.data);
          }
          setState(() {
            _myContacts.length = _myContacts.length;
          });
        }
      });
```

But after the upgrade and refactoring my code to look like below, the parameter is not added to the document.

```
var data = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(firebaseid)
          .collection('contacts')
          .get();
      data.then((QuerySnapshot contacts) {
        if (contacts.docs.isNotEmpty) {
          for (var contact in contacts.docs) {
            contact.data()['isSelected'] = false;       <-- Adding isSelected param
            _myContacts.add(contact.data());
          }
          setState(() {
            _myContacts.length = _myContacts.length;
          });
        }
      });
```

and using these functions doesn't help:
`contact.data().putIfAbsent('isSelected', () => false)`
`contact.data().addAll({'isSelected': false});`

Any help on how to achieve the original purpose of adding new parameters on the fly to document for temporary use.